# Subquery within Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I've written a query that returns a count of open support tickets for a group of agents. The query currently returns tickets that have been older than 5 days:

```
SELECT groupname, 
       assignee, 
       Count(*) AS [Tickets Older Than 5 Days] 
FROM   zendeskunclosedticketexport 
WHERE  ( groupname = 'DC Web Ops' 
          OR groupname = 'DC Maintenance' 
          OR groupname = 'DC QC1' ) 
       AND ticketcreateddate < Dateadd(day, -5, Getdate()) 
GROUP  BY groupname, 
          assignee 
ORDER  BY groupname, 
          Count(*) DESC
```

Query result sample:

```
groupname       assignee                Tickets Older Than 5 Days

DC Maintenance  Mubarak Ali             12
DC Maintenance  Abirami Selvanathan     11
DC Maintenance  Jemima Mohanraj         6
DC Maintenance  Praveena Rajan          6
DC Maintenance  Rahul Ramesh            6
DC Maintenance  Saravanan Varadharajan  6
DC Web Ops  Kasey Barber                16
DC Web Ops  Jamie Raines                11
DC Web Ops  Keith Washington            10
DC Web Ops  Patricia Gomez Imvendorize  6
```

What I have been trying to do is also include columns for 10 days, 30 days, etc. but have been unable to do so. I have attempted to write a subquery within the select statement to return a count for the respective # of days; something like the below:

```
SELECT groupname, 
       assignee [currentAssignee],


       (SELECT Count(*) AS [Tickets Older Than 5 Days] 
            FROM   zendeskunclosedticketexport 
            WHERE  ( 
                    ticketcreateddate < Dateadd(day, -5, Getdate())
                    AND
                    assignee = [currentAssignee]
        )

       (SELECT Count(*) AS [Tickets Older Than 10 Days] 
            FROM   zendeskunclosedticketexport 
            WHERE  ( 
                    ticketcreateddate < Dateadd(day, -10, Getdate())
                    AND
                    assignee = [currentAssignee]
        )

        (SELECT Count(*) AS [Tickets Older Than 30 Days] 
            FROM   zendeskunclosedticketexport 
            WHERE  ( 
                    ticketcreateddate < Dateadd(day, -30, Getdate())
                    AND
                    assignee = [currentAssignee]
        )
FROM   zendeskunclosedticketexport
```

What I am essentially trying to do here is pass the Assignee value from the outer query to the inner queries...I know that as I have it this isn't legal, but hopefully it provides some context as to the approach I'm taking. Is there any way to pass data from an outer query to an inner query in the form of a temporary variable?

EDIT: User notified me that I was missing a FROM clause, have since added this.

Comment: do 3 selects and use union all before grouping

Comment: Your second statement is not complete. Where is the FROM clause for the outer-most query to define what `groupname` and `assignee` are.

Comment: Having trouble posting an answer but the idea is to update your select statements to get the assignee from the base table

Comment: Instead of having the subquries, why not use a CASE and group by 5, 10 and other date ranges..   I think this would cover your needs in a much easier fashion,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this much more simply with a `SUM` of `CASE` statements:

```
SELECT
    groupname,
    assignee,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ticketcreateddate < DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Tickets Older Than 5 Days],
    SUM(CASE WHEN ticketcreateddate < DATEADD(DAY, -10, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Tickets Older Than 10 Days],
    SUM(CASE WHEN ticketcreateddate < DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Tickets Older Than 30 Days]
FROM
    zendeskunclosedticketexport
WHERE
    groupname IN ('DC Web Ops', 'DC Maintenance', 'DC QC1')
GROUP BY
    groupname,
    assignee
ORDER BY
    groupname
```

You can set your `ORDER BY` to whichever of those aggregated columns you need.

Comment: Exactly what I was about to suggest. This is also much more efficient than subselects.

Comment: The other issue with his sub-selects is that it will not return any data correctly.  The 5, 10, and 30 day columns are not separated out by commas.

Comment: Never would have thought to do this myself. Thanks for the help.